# Does a foreigner need an official invitation to visit the United States as a tourist?

Tags: united-states, travel

Does a foreigner (in this case a student from Ukraine) need an official invitation to visit the United States temporarily as a tourist (more specifically not as an immigrant)?

Is there any way an official invitation would help, or alternate method for obtaining a visa that requires an official invitation?

I'm just getting conflicting answers to this question.

Comment: Why did you tag this with "f1-visa"?  And what are the conflicting answers you have gotten?  Have you checked the U.S. State Department's website for tourist information?

Answer (score 2):

[The US Embassy](http://ukraine.usembassy.gov/nonimmigrant-visas.html) has a page on Ukrainian visitors to the US:

> **Who needs a visa?**
>
> Ukrainian citizens require a visa to enter the United States.  Citizens of countries participating in the Visa Waiver Program do not need a visa if their passport meets certain requirements.

So no, you don't need an invitation. You need a visa.

Comment: In some cases, one needs an invitation in order to get a visa. I think that is what the question is asking about.